# Стилизация тегов в WebView

Tags: android

Допустим есть строка `<h1>Привет друзья!</h1>` и она выводится в WebView можно ли программно в Android увеличить стиль текста в теге h1? Например сделать шрифт скажем 18sp и наклон?

Comment: Можете добавить необходимый css стиль в начало строки с html.

Comment: Тоже вариант) Спасибо